# FileNotFoundError while iterating over folders/files in a given directory

Tags: python, logic

The objective of my program is to retrieve all folders' sizes in a given path/directory. The following function is something that I used to calculate a specific folder's size.

```
def get_folder_sz(self, folder_path: str):
    if os.path.isfile(folder_path):
        print('Only folder size can be calculated with the "get_folder_sz" function!"')
        sys.exit(0)

    folder_size = os.stat(folder_path).st_size

    try:
        for item in os.listdir(folder_path):
            item_path = os.path.join(folder_path, item)

            if os.path.isfile(item_path):
                folder_size += os.path.getsize(item_path)
            elif os.path.isdir(item_path):
                folder_size += self.get_folder_sz(item_path)
    except PermissionError as error:
        pass

    return folder_size
```

However, for one reason or another, the program raises the `FileNotFoundError` when calling the function above and I can't seem to find any logical errors in the function that would cause this.

The function only iterates itself if `item` is proven to be a directory, so I'm not sure why the file outputted by `os.listdir` would not be found.

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 53, in <module>
    analyzer.iterate_dir('C:\\', 1)
  File "main.py", line 24, in iterate_dir
    if os.path.isdir(item_path) and self.get_folder_sz(item_path) == 0:
  File "main.py", line 45, in get_folder_sz
    folder_size += self.get_folder_sz(item_path)
  File "main.py", line 45, in get_folder_sz
    folder_size += self.get_folder_sz(item_path)
  File "main.py", line 45, in get_folder_sz
    folder_size += self.get_folder_sz(item_path)
  [Previous line repeated 19 more times]
  File "main.py", line 39, in get_folder_sz
    for item in os.listdir(folder_path):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\8da17c8c9c06e565b531c4225313a5eb\\unzipped-distribution\\gradle-6.3\\subprojects\\build-init\\src\\integTest\\resources\\org\\gradle\\buildinit\\plugins\\MavenConversionIntegrationTest\\expandProperties\\src\\main\\java'
```

I'd appreciate any help possible!

Comment: I am not sure but there are 2 ```\\```

Comment: '\\' is actually just '\' if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Are you talking about the last line of error? @HaruFrost